# Требуется скопировать folder1 в каталог

Tags: python

Очень простая задача, однако не получается выполнить. Требуется скопировать folder1 в каталог D:\savorsk\

```
import shutil

src = "D:\\Project\\2014\\archdata\\folder1"
dst_sav = "D:\\savorsk\\"
shutil.copytree(src, dst_sav)
```

Указанный код приводит к ошибке. Документацию читал очень вдумчиво, но реально не догоняю что в коде не так.

```
D:\123>1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\123\1.py", line 5, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(src, dst_sav)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\shutil.py", line 175, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 183] ═хтючьюцэю ёючфрЄ№ Їрщы,: 'D:\\savorsk'
```

Comment: Вы хоть ошибку покажите

Comment: попробуйте так:

    shutil.copytree('D:\\Project\\2014\\archdata\\folder1', 'D:\\savorsk\\folder1')

Comment: Добавил ее. Как я понимаю эта штука пытается каталог savorsk создать, но мне это не нужно. Мне нужно в него скопировать все.

Comment: Я понять не могу, а как же мне быть, если у меня в коде переменные путей формируются на лету. Я реально логику не понимаю.

Comment: Не могли бы показать пример кода как скопировать нужный каталог в целевой. Просто сейчас я логику не понимаю.

Просто я реально не понимаю как в dst_sav = "D:\\savorsk\\" попадает folder1

Comment: Выше и есть кусок кода, который копирует нужный какталог в целевой.
Я не понимаю в чем у вас может быть проблема.

Из документации copytree:

> Рекурсивно копирует дерево каталогов с корнем в src. Каталог назначения, названный dst, не должен существовать; он будет создан.

Если вас смущает то, что в пути назначения нужно указывать имя исходного каталога - то вы всегда его можете получить из пути src используя os.path.basename и склеить с помощью os.path.join

    dst = os.path.join(dst_sav, os.path.basename(src))
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вы хоть ошибку покажите

WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists : 'D:\savorsk'

> Как я понимаю эта штука пытается каталог savorsk создать, но мне это не нужно.

Проблема в том, что если целевая папку уже существует на диске, то shutil.copytree() всегда возвращает ошибку.

> Не могли бы показать пример кода как скопировать нужный каталог в целевой

```
import os
import shutil

def my_copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = "D:\\Project\\2014\\archdata\\folder1"
    dst_sav = "D:\\savorsk\\"    
    my_copytree(src, dst_sav)
```